# Config values in Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I'm developing a PCL that will be used by Windows Store and WP8 apps. This library requires some configuration e.g. remote service url. I wanted to put those into the app.config and retrieve them using ConfigurationManager, but the System.Configuration doesn't seem to be available in PCL.

Comment: A normal library accessing `ConfigurationManager` looks a bit dubious to me. Shouldn't that be the responsibility of the application, which then passes a configuration object to the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a configuration class. In the simplest case<sup>1</sup> it could look like:

```
public class MyLibraryConfig
{
    public string RemoteServiceUrl{get;set;}
}
```

Then pass an instance of this class to the library via standard dependency injection techniques. For example pass it into the constructor and store it in a field. Then it's the application's responsibility to read the configuration from a file, the `ConfigurationManager`, etc.

IMO this is much better design and I'd use it over querying the configuration manager even in libraries where I could access the `ConfigurationManager`. Else you force the application to use a single configuration and to use a specific configuration mechanism.

---

<sup>1</sup> you can also use an interface or an immutable class. That's slightly more complex, but IMO better design.

Comment: can you justify why using app settings in a library class is such a bad thing? Wasn't this configuration mechanism designed to be used in this way?

Comment: Deciding on which configuration to use is the applications responsibility, not the responsibility of a library. Accessing `ConfigurationManager` in your application's startup code is fine, but accessing it in a library is not. Avoiding access to `ConfigurationManager` in a library is a special case of avoiding singletons and global variables. What if you want two instantiations of the library within a single process? How do you supply test configs? What if the consumer of the library uses a different configuration mechanism?

Comment: AppSettings, as its name suggests is a collection of application-specific settings. A library represents code that can be reused by different applications, and these applications may have different ways of grouping their settings. And of course if you are working with a portable class library you should find more generalized way of accessing configuration information than relying on AppSettings.